# Output only the date in a parsed email using php

Tags: php, parsing, email

How can I get the parse email to only show the Date like Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 10:38:13 instead of the sample below

> Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 10:38:13 -0400 Subject: Sample E-mail From:
>   user To: user Message-ID: Thread-Topic: Sample E-mail Thread-Index:
>   Ac0nqAlw+FJmG2FhRUuM8nhAxVUpjA== Mime-version: 1.0 Content-type:
>   multipart/alternative; boundary=\"B_3418713494_2606128\" >

```
$date2 = substr($email, strripos($email,"Date:")+strlen("Date:"));
$date = explode("Delivered To:", $date2);
echo "<br /><br /> Date: " . $date[0];
```

Comment: Try regex to get date, sample regex - `^(Date:)?\s+[a-zA-z]+,?\s+?[0-3][0-9]\s+?[a-zA-z]+\s+?\d{4}\s+\d{2}:?\d{2}:?\d{2}$`, php manual on how to use regex - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust `Date:` is followed by `Subject:` the following could work as an alternative to a Regex solution (and thus its overhead).

```
$pos = strpos('Subject:', $mail_header);
if ($pos !== false) {
  $date = substr($mail_header, 0, $pos);
  echo $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm unserstanding what you want, the following should work - change

```
echo "<br /><br /> Date: " . $date[0];
```

to

```
echo "<br /><br /> Date: " . date( "D, d M Y g:i:s", strtotime( $date[0] ) );
```

Manual references: [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) Class!

Note: (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)

Since the date format given is a standard unvarying length you can also use substr to parse the string:

```
$date = date_create(
    substr($email,6,25)
);

echo $date->format('D, d M Y g:i:s'); //or any valid format you want
```